# Datatable Grouping Using Linq and VB .NET

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable, grouping

I'm completely dense here, but I'm trying to get some stats from a DataTable.  One of the columns in the datatable is called "colour".

I need to find out how many of each instance of "colour" are in the datatable.

I'm trying:

```
Dim q = From p In PGWorkingDataTable _
            Group p By p("colour") Into Group _
            Select Group
```

But I get the compiler error at design-time:
"Range variable name can be inferred only from a simple or qualified name with no arguments" on the p("colour") section.

I need some serious guidance here.  Thanks for your help.

Joe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify a name for the group key:

```
From p In new DataTable() _
Group p By Color = p("colour") Into Group _
Select Group
```

Comment: I had a code completion error on this snippet originally, but now it seems to compile just fine!  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Writing LINQ in VB.NET is nobody's favorite thing.  Try something like the following:

```
Dim q = From p In PGWorkingDataTable _
        Group By colour = p("colour") _
        Into colourCount = Count(p("colour")) _
        Select colour, colourCount
```

Comment: I keep getting this error: "Conversion from "Light Gray" to Boolean is not valid.  "Light Gray", of course, is one of the values in the colour column of my datatable.  Any further pointers?

Comment: Basically I need to take these results and plot them on a winforms chart control.  So is the variable "q" now a datatable in and of itself?  Or something I can bind to a chart control maybe?  Thank you!

Comment: Can you use LINQPad to see what the results actually are?  You should be getting an IEnumerable of anonymous type containing each color (colour) and the number of times it occurs (colourCount) - I only provided it in that syntax because you used it in the question.  If you want the DataRows themselves, you can use @SLaks' answer; I just figured you'd want that data.  If you'd like, that last line can read `Select New KeyValuePair(colour, colourCount)`, and you can declare q as an IEnumerable of KeyValuePairs (or however you'd like to hold on to the data).